# %load_ext rpy2.ipython in Pycharm gives SyntaxError

Tags: pycharm, syntax-error, rpy2

rpy2 imports with no issue but
`%load_ext rpy2.ipython` and
`%%R`
come up with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Any idea what I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those are so-called "magic" commands for ipython or Jupyter (and other software based on them).

Pycharm has a an integration with Jupyter. The doc about it may provide help:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html